# How to hold & release print jobs using cups?

Tags: linux, printing, printer, cron, cups

I have installed `CUPS 1.6.3` on `centos 7`. I am trying to find a solution to hold printing jobs from 6pm Friday to 6am Monday but I'm not sure how to do it.

I found few commands but I'm not sure how to use them as there is no example. Commands I'm looking after are: `Hold-New-Jobs` & `Release-Held-New-Jobs` from page https://www.cups.org/doc/spec-ipp.html#IPP_OPERATIONS.

I want to run a cron with command to `Hold-New-Jobs` at 6PM Friday and then another cron to `Release-Held-New-Jobs` on Monday 6am.

I have a printer named `Printer2`. Can you please help me with above?

**UPDATE**

Below cron job did the trick.

```
# hold print jobs on Printer2 at 6pm Friday.
0 18 * * 5 /usr/sbin/cupsdisable --hold Printer2 >/dev/null 2>&1

# release print jobs from Printer2 at 6am Monday
0 06 * * 1 /usr/sbin/cupsenable --release Printer2 >/dev/null 2>&1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run a cron job to disable the queue at 6pm on Friday (`cupsdisable <queue>`).  Then run another cron job to re-enable the queue at 6am on Monday (`cupsenable <queue>`).

Queues disabled with `cupsdisable` will accept new jobs, but won't process them.

Comment: Thank you. Used that command and it worked. See updated question for the syntax used.